# How to constrain argument to supertype but keep reference to full type for return value?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to do a stunt in deduplicating code with full type safety. Basically, in my project I have a bunch of things that all *should* extend the same interface but they don't because the property names vary in each type. I cannot just change them, because they are tied to the database. Which I know is generally bad but in this particular case it's awesome.

So, I want to write a function that can operate on all of these different types by passing in extra info that acts as an adapter. I'm able to make it work, but I loose the type information of the object I'm working on. I need to keep it, because the return value should have that type, not some supertype.

Here's the code:

```js
interface Sized {
  width: number;
  height: number;
}

interface Positioned {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

/**
 * Adjusts `element`'s position so that it fits into the given `container`.
 *
 * `element` and `container` can have arbitrary property names for their dimensions.
 * `elKeys` and `cKeys` map them to standard `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` properties.
 *
 * `elKeys` and `cKeys` must be declared using "as const" assertion,
 * so Typescript is aware of their literal types to be able to check
 * that they are compatible.
 */
function fitElementIntoContainer<
  E extends string,
  C extends string
>(
  element: { [key in E]: number },
  container: { [key in C]: number },
  elKeys: string extends E ? never : { [key in keyof (Sized & Positioned)]: E },
  cKeys: string extends C ? never : { [key in keyof Sized]: C },
  elementMinWidth?: number,
  elementMinHeight?: number
) {
  const mutEl = { ...element };
  const x = mutEl[elKeys.x];
  if (mutEl[elKeys.x] < 0) mutEl[elKeys.x] = 0;
  if (mutEl[elKeys.y] < 0) mutEl[elKeys.y] = 0;
  
  if (mutEl[elKeys.x] + mutEl[elKeys.width] > container[cKeys.width]) {
    mutEl[elKeys.x] = container[cKeys.width] - mutEl[elKeys.width];
  }
  if (mutEl[elKeys.y] + mutEl[elKeys.height] > container[cKeys.height]) {
    mutEl[elKeys.y] = container[cKeys.height] - mutEl[elKeys.height];
  }
  
  if (elementMinWidth !== undefined && mutEl[elKeys.width] < elementMinWidth) {
    mutEl[elKeys.width] = elementMinWidth;
  }
  if (elementMinHeight !== undefined && mutEl[elKeys.height] < elementMinHeight) {
    mutEl[elKeys.height] = elementMinHeight;
  }
  
  return mutEl;
}

interface Chair {
  chairX: number;
  chairY: number;
  chairWidth: number
  chairHeight: number;
  color: string; // one extra prop that has nothing to do with dimensions
}

const exampleElement: Chair = {
  chairX: -3,
  chairY: 55,
  chairWidth: 40,
  chairHeight: 40,
  color: 'black'
}

const exampleContainer = {
  cW: 555,
  cH: 3300
};

const containerKeys = {
  width: "cW",
  height: "cH"
} as const;

const chairKeys = {
  x: "chairX",
  y: "chairY",
  width: "chairWidth",
  height: "chairHeight"
} as const;

// Error: Property 'color' is missing in type '{ chairX: number; chairY: number; chairWidth: number; chairHeight: number; }' 
// but required in type 'Chair'.(2741)
const fitsIntoContainer: Chair = fitElementIntoContainer(
  exampleElement,
  exampleContainer,
  chairKeys,
  containerKeys
);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMrAF4QCbIN4BQyyA7sNmABYBcyIArgLYBG0A3EcpRMAOaVhaDFuwIBfAgVCRYiFAAUA9gGdgYYIpA58nAB5CmrKB2IBPAyOPjJAegBUdoneQBBbACt6ysMuQADCAAbCEYIcD8Acl8ABxU1DRBkZUVkKjgwZDVkGDVfaRSqFF5gADcw-wRNMDhQaD8AOicnfyCQsLA-ZDgQXD9K8BqtKE6Ebq44Mq6oZjUoOChTZGioRWjoMEWQOFDfGEUoVO5gA+xgUJBVTWVG5DsAwIBpCFNlTu7ehCeXzsY4aMOQqkUt53vNero-AAafymKH+MgUShvHr+I78DpLFZrKDqCDXJq3e5fV5dFF9Yk-LwZVjIbAQBCBebaLygXjIABEcF8-W87K6ymU6wSkOayWQABVTGtlAgoMBohlgL44CQmchFDAAcdkIE1NA4IFUlK8UDkDS4MxgqaENwEABrZppDKFRZqyqMaLpYCWiA3Ow2AgweggBDqTTZNQAUWC5zAAElwIoAMJVQbQAA8nEjyAgukgPV83jlIF4IuISZzebC2ELYGLvAIAD4ABScVqx2h4ZAAbTtz0yiUjAF0LEZkGIy8h+tValBOz2+4tQMgkyO6IZoOPJ0FibQi6zK-ma8hswB+OgQMoHee9-vLxca5DN9BYXAAMmQSlUYa02AAlGu2YTpwnzPMoe51geuZHr4FbnloV7IDei4DsgD6ai+OBrhWwHEO27QALKgAA6uQVCnqO0DbjGhGgAAEjw6IUeulgEH+OjEDyGSMPQYDRsgAC8+DIPUon4eA44mFOVwZLognIDxfGBN2O5gfUuhDlJwCas2inRipjxqRpyDpsgAAM7F6cpqkvOpQ7yWZWk6VZBnEvUpj2aZFkKbx+k2dcHkOVJnDaU+Ln+XZyAANQ+UprlqQiVD2Y20kDLO3agbZiWUEO7GEMQxDhYZtnGUJ05plAGVudl9kALSxX5xXXDVUkSMQoW6b51lNe59kxUVblogIyWpTOQxVWpQ1gLlHEFQNamBWVqbpZl1xTXVDXdYNjHDa1nAhTp4lgERICkYiyAAIQCUJwZ0jkv7IG+H7zVlZE5SZOY0eAJ1nVQeWcIVXXxa9iL2UJR0-W9e3tYdX3HfRO0ZFdN09BA93aE9m3A2tiOeZ9bTfQjfACP9BVYxF63yRDRPotDyCcFAEBgPQUCJFZHASFI4DQPASArpQNQHPlU4C8cAAalFWJxotQAAmpLUk2oLv00CxRggTLDHE4IauiJxiiBPsEH1mwyA2DY6paIecyYqshzpOMvggIoVAHmAKTYCkZBULSZxhJcFzWAQXGVts0TBNGBM60mMvycLSvi7QtUAMyTgncu0AArJnacyyrtAACxmbngta+ihfFyBBtG8gESWogdoREHIe5mHwQpmlQxxyBxFZ9nad0bQyfJ2ZZniBwwcyaNFXEt3xDZbQ7IIMR7KTlNi8IHR7LiPyqXeBPIfp7PQnC-oHLp2Lq+cOY58y7LV-z29G9529D9cIjz+l4j29iLvXEH1PHIPgEzuw7mNaAtAY6C3kkAyOsYQHJmWkMZsrcPQRzhtCVB4cIBgIqtCI+YF8FIOgMSP8bAgA)

I have tried many variations, but something always breaks. Is this possible?

Comment: ① The problem should be explicitly shown in plaintext in the question to be a [mre]; a playground link is a nice supplement but it doesn't suffice. ② Are you more concerned with the *typings* or the *implementation*?  I mean, can we just write `declare function fitElementIntoContainer...` with a proper call signature and not worry about the implementation to proceed here?

Comment: ③ What you're calling a "subtype" is a "supertype"; more properties is more specific, which is a subtype, not a supertype. ④Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/W46p4N) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: ① This thing has a lot of code, so I thought I'd reduce it here to "the minimum". But you're right, it's better to have a full version of it here. Updated

Comment: ② At this point it's more about understanding TS than getting work done. Tough I'm not certain how `declare function...` would help, since the point definetly is to keep users of the function from passing in incompatible adapter objects. This is particularly important since this _will_ change eventually, and then I want to find all instances of code that break.

Comment: ③ Thanks for pointing out the proper nomenclature here. I still find this confusing sometimes, but your explanation helped me understand it a lot

Comment: ④ I have been able to simplify your example a bit [on line 15](https://tsplay.dev/mxx5Bm). Other than that, except for taking a slightly different approach in defining the input types, it's only real difference is using `any` internally. That's kind of a trivial solution, sacrificing safety. Given that this is well-scoped to the function body, it's bearable. But it is not the savvy little trick I was hoping for

Comment: Your simplification makes the assumption that the output type will be the same as the input type, but if the input has numeric literal types as properties then you might be surprised: see [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m0xLnm) for a demo (and note that my earlier suggestion was also slightly wrong so I've fixed it).  The point about `declare function` is that I don't want to worry both about call side typing and implementation typing, since they are essentially separate problems given the inability for the compiler to strongly type generic conditional types for the "correct" typing.

Comment: (continued) In my example I wrote `any` because I didn't want to worry about implementation typing, without knowing that it was crucial to the question.  So... should I write up an answer or not?  I notice while I've been fretting about this @Dimava went ahead and wrote up an answer, so I'm not sure if it's worth it.  Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz with your and Dimava's help I have come up with two different solutions, both without assertions. One is computationally efficient but can cause those issues with literal types that you mentioned (funny this is possible without assertions), the other is less efficient but does not rely on a mutable approach. It's got the same type problem though!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A somewhat despicable approach, because it weirdly relies on mutability, is this:

```js
interface Sized {
  width: number;
  height: number;
}

interface Positioned {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

/**
 * Adjusts `element`'s position so that it fits into the given `container`.
 *
 * `element` and `container` can have arbitrary property names for their dimensions.
 *`elKeys` and `cKeys` map them to standard `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` properties.
 *
 *`elKeys` and `cKeys` must be declared using "as const" assertion,
 * so Typescript is aware of their literal types to be able to check
 * that they are compatible.
 */
export function fitElementIntoContainer<
  U extends { [key in E]: number },
  E extends string,
  C extends string
>(
  element: U,
  container: { [key in C]: number },
  elKeys: string extends E ? never : { [key in keyof (Sized & Positioned)]: E },
  cKeys: string extends C ? never : { [key in keyof Sized]: C },
  elementMinWidth?: number,
  elementMinHeight?: number
) {
  const keepTypeAndReturn = { ...element };
  const broadenTypeAndEdit: { [key in E]: number } = keepTypeAndReturn;
  if (broadenTypeAndEdit[elKeys.x] < 0) broadenTypeAndEdit[elKeys.x] = 0;
  if (broadenTypeAndEdit[elKeys.y] < 0) broadenTypeAndEdit[elKeys.y] = 0;

  if (broadenTypeAndEdit[elKeys.x] + broadenTypeAndEdit[elKeys.width] > container[cKeys.width]) {
    broadenTypeAndEdit[elKeys.x] = container[cKeys.width] - broadenTypeAndEdit[elKeys.width];
  }
  if (broadenTypeAndEdit[elKeys.y] + broadenTypeAndEdit[elKeys.height] > container[cKeys.height]) {
    broadenTypeAndEdit[elKeys.y] = container[cKeys.height] - broadenTypeAndEdit[elKeys.height];
  }

  if (elementMinWidth !== undefined && broadenTypeAndEdit[elKeys.width] < elementMinWidth) {
    broadenTypeAndEdit[elKeys.width] = elementMinWidth;
  }
  if (elementMinHeight !== undefined && broadenTypeAndEdit[elKeys.height] < elementMinHeight) {
    broadenTypeAndEdit[elKeys.height] = elementMinHeight;
  }

  return keepTypeAndReturn;
}
```

Good is that this has no added runtime complexity just to keep the type info.

Interestingly enough, this causes the returned type to diverge from the value when `element` contains literal values:

```js
const exampleElement = {
  chairX: -3,
  chairY: 55,
  chairWidth: 40,
  chairHeight: 40,
  color: 'black'
} as const;

const exampleContainer = {
  cW: 555,
  cH: 3300
};

const containerKeys = {
  width: "cW",
  height: "cH"
} as const;

const chairKeys = {
  x: "chairX",
  y: "chairY",
  width: "chairWidth",
  height: "chairHeight"
} as const;

const fitsIntoContainer = fitElementIntoContainer(
  exampleElement,
  exampleContainer,
  chairKeys,
  containerKeys
);

// type of chairX is still -3, but value is 0
console.log(fitsIntoContainer)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMrAF4QCbIN4BQyyA7sNmABYBcyIArgLYBG0A3EcpRMAOaVhaDFuwIBfAgVCRYiFAAUA9gGdgYYIpA58nAB5CmrKB2IBPAyOPjJAegBUdoneQBBbACt6ysMuQADCAAbCEYIcD8Acl8ABxU1DRBkZUVkKjgwZDVkGDVfaRSqFF5gADcw-wRNMDhQaD8AOicnfyCQsLA-ZDgQXD9K8BqtKE6Ebq44Mq6oZjUoOChTZGioRWjoMEWQOFDfGEUoVO5gA+xgUJBVTWVG5DsAwIBpCFNlTu7ehCeXzsY4aMOQqkUt53vNero-AAafymKH+MgUShvHr+I78DpLFZrKDqCDXJq3e5fV5dFF9Yk-LwZVjIbAQBCBebaLygXjIABEcF8-W87K6ymU6wSkOayWQABVTGtlAgoMBohlgL44CQmchFDAAcdkIE1NA4IFUlK8UDkDS4MxgqaENwEABrZppDKFRZqyqMaLpYCWiA3Ow2AgweggBDqTTZNQAUWC5zAAElwIoAMJVQbQAA8nAAqsgILpID1fHhkABtO3PTKJSMAXQsRmQYhFxEjufzYWwvm8cpAvCbyCTrYLHaSYG7vAIAD4ABScVqx2hZvv9aq1KC0Ytliugfu1uiGaANvtBYm0Luswft3wtgD8dAgZQO69L5cW25fGuQU-QWFwADJkEoqhhlo2AAJS7i2jacJ8zzKKeo7nnmQ6+AOt5aA+yBPpur6JO+mrfjgu4DlBxBzu0ACyoAAOrkFQ151tAR4xhRoAABI8Oi9F7pYBCgToxA8hk5YQNEkprC4PQAEoQGA9BQIkAC8+DIPUqlkeADYmMgglmiscB0iAYkQBJ2CRqcgjKdhlbIDWDEHGIyBKcJonGiZ0myfJWnAJqU7MHpBlGSZZlqCWx6wfUujVsg6bIAADHxfmKPpYSBT0wVgKFjzhZFjlxV5PmJclhmuWl5mZcS9SmFFMXxbpSUBSVpllWFLyVVFSmxRwnDeZ+hUNeJpUhS11w5QA1HVRWpU1Q1Za1CJUFFE7aamq4ljBc20ZQ1Z8YQxDEH1KWNel5XZe1y0DKt63XPNW3IAAtBN-XGYNGXDfUN3VlpEjED1vn+YdA3Ta9s3XFVyDjQdxWA8db1ogIi3nSuQxrRVcNgNt-F7ZDU0wyDbW5cuaZQCj4Vo1FD3Y0dzV42TX2SD9PnqWAlEgDRiLIAAhApSnBnSOQgcgv7-pT0PUxVH3RbmzHgCzbNUDtnD7f9UPPUDJ0bYiZ1M7Lm10wzn7a2xHECJz3PILzED89oQuPQDqu46jxvo5LhsgOxfACAre22yrQVi6TTta9LzNGx7YB05wUAyXJuEQCJU3uTHHASAQOl5ts0TBNGbQaUpu3aZQNRQAAGrQd0AMxLoXxwAJq0AArPXVdF3LNDIAALLFzfHO76K0J3S6KIE+y0BElqIHaETiPy53eF1ae6BnwQphdQy5fnCBUQ3jdLqxtDl+XsWxeI89XBkhOrsS6+cDdtDspv7J9mjd8IKx7LT1ys-h5IOk2kXV95z0C-auJdH6cHMByP+tcwHEFvpAkBrcYFcCdsAouvcBDvwcp-QSp8LgZByD4BMYBkwrTXkpAh2dYxEJIavaAM5SKLw9FnYOR5GGZwgCvJGjFoIgOJIPWhUBiS8VwckYI9Rh68CnAQ5Q1DOFE1AkAA)

Answer (score 0):

You may make this by adding an extra generic type to keep the parameter type: https://tsplay.dev/wQ0KVW

```
/**
 * Adjusts `element`'s position so that it fits into the given `container`.
 *
 * `element` and `container` can have arbitrary property names for their dimensions.
 * `elKeys` and `cKeys` map them to standard `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` properties.
 *
 * `elKeys` and `cKeys` must be declared using "as const" assertion,
 * so Typescript is aware of their literal types to be able to check
 * that they are compatible.
 */
function fitElementIntoContainer<
  E extends string,
  C extends string,
  const Element extends Record<E, number>, // to keep the type
>(
  element: Element,
  container: { [key in C]: number },
  elKeys: Record<keyof (Sized & Positioned), E>,
  cKeys: Record<keyof Sized, C>,
  elementMinWidth?: number,
  elementMinHeight?: number
): Element {
  const copy = { ...element }
  // cast to make sure all keys are numbers
  const mutEl = copy as Record<E, number>;

  // min/max may be more understandable then ifs, optional.
  mutEl[elKeys.x] = Math.max(mutEl[elKeys.x], 0); 
  mutEl[elKeys.y] = Math.max(mutEl[elKeys.y], 0);

  mutEl[elKeys.x] = Math.min(mutEl[elKeys.x], container[cKeys.width] - mutEl[elKeys.width]);
  mutEl[elKeys.y] = Math.min(mutEl[elKeys.y], container[cKeys.height] - mutEl[elKeys.height]);

  mutEl[elKeys.width] = Math.max(mutEl[elKeys.width], elementMinWidth ?? 0)
  mutEl[elKeys.height] = Math.max(mutEl[elKeys.height], elementMinHeight ?? 0)

  return copy;
}
```

Comment: I like the `Math.max` approach. I've been weighing using it against my version for a while, but came to the conclusion that mine is more readable for total beginners (and possibly a tiny little bit more efficient??!). Your cast is significantly more benign than jcalz' `any` but it's still a cast, which I hate until there is a `safeas` operator for casts that _only broaden_ the type. I believe this would work without the extra generic, though, wouldn't it? Unless somebody comes around who figures this out without using `as` and loose types, I'll accept this answer

Comment: @NoBullsh1t the problem is that you may have the type `interface Chair { chairX: -123; /* wut */ }`  and then you can't just set it to 0, so the return type already doesnt match input type. TS takes those cases into account so you have to cast Element to the Record you believe it is.

Comment: @NoBullsh1t I would disagree about "more readable for total beginners": 1) Your `width` lines have different code if `if` and `body` making it error-prone. 2) It's easy to make mistake in `>/<` or `+/-` or subtraction order. 3) I just think that "Make this value minimum of itself and (another value)" more simple even for beginners then "If this value plus something is larger then something, set it to something different"

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that literal numbers are the root cause. For the keys, there is this black magic approach to actually disallow `string` when we need literals. Here, I'd need the opposite: Disallow literals and force `number`. That's what I'm looking for, if it exists

Comment: @NoBullsh1t do you want to convert or to error?

Comment: I believe in this instance the cast is actually reliably safe, as one can only pass in `number` or a union of number literals. I dislike having the cast in my code base because it sets an example that using it is okay, and juniors won't work out that I have carefully made sure it does not fail, here. Like I said, convert would be fine if `safeas` existed, but it doesn't. So I would _prefer_ to prevent, keeping my type system "tight"

Comment: @NoBullsh1t here's https://tsplay.dev/wExD4W with overridden types if dismatch

Comment: @NoBullsh1t working with `generic extends Record` is the one place where `as` is unaviodable very very often. I would like if there was ESLint rule requiring banning casts, so you have to `@eslint-disable` it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253571/discussion-between-nobullsh1t-and-dimava).

Answer (score 0):

A solution, precise in the type but annoyingly unnecessarily computation heavy, is the following:

```js
interface Sized {
  width: number;
  height: number;
}

interface Positioned {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

/**
 * Adjusts `element`'s position so that it fits into the given `container`.
 *
 * `element` and `container` can have arbitrary property names for their dimensions.
 *`elKeys` and `cKeys` map them to standard `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` properties.
 *
 *`elKeys` and `cKeys` must be declared using "as const" assertion,
 * so Typescript is aware of their literal types to be able to check
 * that they are compatible.
 */
function fitElementIntoContainer<
  U extends { [key in E]: number },
  E extends string,
  C extends string
>(
  element: U,
  container: { [key in C]: number },
  elKeys: string extends E ? never : { [key in keyof (Sized & Positioned)]: E },
  cKeys: string extends C ? never : { [key in keyof Sized]: C },
  elementMinWidth?: number,
  elementMinHeight?: number
): U {
  const mutEl: { [key in E]: number } = { ...element };
  if (mutEl[elKeys.x] < 0) mutEl[elKeys.x] = 0;
  if (mutEl[elKeys.y] < 0) mutEl[elKeys.y] = 0;
  
  if (mutEl[elKeys.x] + mutEl[elKeys.width] > container[cKeys.width]) {
    mutEl[elKeys.x] = container[cKeys.width] - mutEl[elKeys.width];
  }
  if (mutEl[elKeys.y] + mutEl[elKeys.height] > container[cKeys.height]) {
    mutEl[elKeys.y] = container[cKeys.height] - mutEl[elKeys.height];
  }
  
  if (elementMinWidth !== undefined && mutEl[elKeys.width] < elementMinWidth) {
    mutEl[elKeys.width] = elementMinWidth;
  }
  if (elementMinHeight !== undefined && mutEl[elKeys.height] < elementMinHeight) {
    mutEl[elKeys.height] = elementMinHeight;
  }
  
  return {
    ...element,
    ...mutEl
  };
}
```

It uses assignment to a broader type to, well, broaden the type of `element`. To get the orginial type back, we spread both the originial `element` as well as the modified variant back into the return value. TS can follow this (partly), no assertions needed.

Even though it appears as if this approach follows the two most important rules for a clean type system (no assertions, immutable approach), the return type is **still incorrect** if `element` contains literal number types for its values!